`Span<T>` iteration/indexer is SLOWER than Array, why?
So I have a method that creates an Array and calculates every element;
//pseudo code
public static void MyMethod(int length)
{
    char[] output = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = DoStuff(i);
    }
}

Now, interestingly, if I use a Span - the code (expectedy) uses 5X less memomry, but becomes 20% slower (did a BDN benchmark on .NET 8)
public static void MyMethod(int length)
{
    Span<char> output = stackalloc char[length]; //this line is the only change
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = DoStuff(i);
    }
}

Why? I thought Span's are supposed to be faster?
My assumption is: maybe because arrays are fixed-length, the compiler is smart and removes bound checks inside the loop, because it "knows" that the loop is only within the array bounds.
However Span's length can change, so the bound check is ALWAYS executed.
Any other explanation? And how can I get rid of those bound checks? Tried using unsafe and fixed char* but same results.
UPDATE: found a similar thread on reddit that also suggests bound checks, and that local arrays can indeed be faster than Spans https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/vatl0g/span_vs_array_performance/ (check the 2nd comment)

For a question like this it would really help to provide minimal repro code instead of pseudocode. In my testing (.NET 7) I'm seeing that declaring output as a Span<> adds a small perf hit (~10%) and stackalloc makes it go a little faster (5%) when compiler optimization is turned off; but with compiler optimization enabled Span makes no significant difference while stackalloc makes it about 15% faster. But lots can change based on length, what DoStuff does, and anything else that might be different between your implementation and mine.

Sure, index checking elimination is one of the standard jitter optimizations.  Works for array, not for span.  Span doesn't start to pay off until you need a slice of an array.

@HansPassant bounds check elimination works for spans, it even works for this span in this code: in this example loop is from L0060 to L0070 (no bounds check)

Here is another example of bounds check elimination working for a Span

"but becomes 20% slower (did a BDN benchmark)" - not sure if BND account the potential GC cost so saving memory can have more significant impact than the loop cost.

For proper testing, you should really find a way to separate the loop itself from the allocation and DoStuff.

A simple test in LinqPad for .NET 7 using this setup https://dotnetfiddle.net/GrKgQi got me the following | Method    | Mean     | Error     | StdDev    | |---------- |---------:|----------:|----------:| | MyMethod  | 3.390 μs | 0.0265 μs | 0.0222 μs | | MyMethod2 | 3.627 μs | 0.0459 μs | 0.0430 μs | so it does seem like there is some overhead. Having said tha, trying it on larger arrays moved it the other way as did more runs, so maybe it was just standard margin of error.

IMHO a problem is probably for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++). Otherwise the compiler may have trouble knowing that length == output.Length, and that output[i] is always inbounds.
